# My PHP code snipptet in Wordpress is not executing

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, elementor

I have the following code used on the Thank You pages. It gets executed once the user fills out a form. It worked perfectly fine for months but suddenly it's not working.

When I insert an echo statement before IF statements it prints a message, but not after the first IF statement.

```
<?php

// Make sure we have a post ID
if ( isset( $_GET['post'] ) ) {

    // Load the resource
    $resource = get_post( (int) $_GET['post'] );

    // Make sure the supplied 'post' parameter returns an object
    if ( is_object( $resource ) ) {

        $title =  esc_html( get_the_title( $resource->ID ) );

        if ( $title === '' ) {
            $title = 'White Paper';
        }

        // Maybe display the video embed code
        $video_embed_code = get_field( 'video_embed_code', $resource->ID );
        if ( $video_embed_code ) {

            echo '<div class="video_embed_code">';

                echo $video_embed_code;

            echo '</div>';

        }

        // Maybe display the whitepaper URL
        $access_link = get_field( 'access_link', $resource->ID );
        if ( $access_link ) {

            echo '<div class="access_link">';

                echo '<a href="' . $access_link . '" class="button button-1">Download ' . $title . '</a>';

            echo '</div>';

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you looked in the server error log? What did you find there?

Comment: Yes, I did. Nothing was recorded there rather than a plugin warnings and deprecated code.

Comment: PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /www/roirevolution_393/public/wp-content/plugins/shortcode-cleaner/vendor/codestar/codestar/core/Helper/Helper.php on line 325
[26-Aug-2022 13:34:03 UTC] 

PHP Deprecated:  The called constructor method for WPSEO_Admin_Asset_Yoast_Components_L10n class is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 18.0! Use <code>__construct()</code> instead. in /www/roirevolution_393/public/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5483

Comment: How does the `<form>` look like? Does the php enter the first if `isset( $_GET['post'] )` ? the second?

Comment: The form is simple and it's built under Marketo. And then it sends the user to a Thank you page

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was the problem. I compressed JQuery with other scripts and it was loaded at the end of the page. Moved it to the top of the page and voila!